# Handling an HTTP Connect with Netty 4

Tags: netty

My library [*Betamax*](http://freeside.co/betamax) is for stubbing out HTTP endpoints for unit tests. It operates as an HTTP(S) proxy and in HTTPS mode is essentially performing a MITM attack. Using Jetty it spins up two proxy instances and responds to an HTTP Connect on the HTTP port by tunneling to the HTTPS port.

I'm trying to replace Jetty with Netty as a dependency. When trying to replicate this functionality with Netty 4.0.7.Final I'm getting stuck handling the *CONNECT* & SSL handshake. Something is missing as instead of a new *GET* request going to the proxy when I accept the *CONNECT* the *CONNECT* request itself is just getting re-routed.

Is there an example of handling an HTTP *CONNECT* with Netty 4? I've looked at the secure chat example from Netty but the socks protocol is quite different to an HTTP proxy protocol. I've also seen LittleProxy and that's been helpful up to a point but it's using an older version of Netty and the API has changed quite a bit.